# Error while installing vmware in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I tried many times to install vmware but I always get an error at the end of installing. Please see picture, what can I do? I downloaded 12 versions, also latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few steps:

1. First get some required tools:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) gksu
   ```
2. Download vmplayer
3. The installation bundle must be executable:

   ```
   chmod +x VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle
   ```
4. Make sure you are in the correct directory and run:

   ```
   gksudo bash VMware-Player-12.0.1-3160714.x86_64.bundle
   ```

Remembering that the actual name of your downloaded bundle may differ from my example...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Docs: VMware/Player](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player)